# "User Was Removed" negative reputation color coding

Tags: feature-request, deleted-users, reputation-history

On Color Psychology:

Before I begin, I'd like to make sure you are aware of the ["User Was Removed"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) reputation change, please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) to learn about it.

Now,

When I get negative rep because a [user was removed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) the "-5" is red which in my mind is associated with my doing something that earned me negative reputation. In this case I didn't do anything that deserved negative reputation, I received +5 rep from this user, then their account was deleted so it went back down to zero, (+5 and -5 has net "0")... so the "red" doesn't make much sense, since it wasn't a loss, but a break-even.

I propose making the "-5" a grey color so it's neutral and more clear that your net-gain reputation is zero and not negative. As opposed to negative rep which is when I have a net-loss reputation due to something I did which isn't neutral but negative and should be red.

Any thoughts?
[image]

Comment: Not sure why I was down-voted, any clarification?

Comment: I'd suggest making the post into a [tag:feature-request], and describe exactly what you are suggesting and what it would entail.  Just asking for a discussion on the color itself might be something for [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com) (note: not a discussion - pose it as a problem of 'the red color indicates something negative, how do you avoid this for a negative score for something that isn't anyone's "fault"?').  As it is, what are you expecting from the outcome of this question? ... and note, that my stock prices show red sometimes too, even though I didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: Downvotes here are because people disagree with your perceived problem and/or the solution you proposed for that perceived problem. This *is* a feature request. You are proposing that the color be changed from red to grey. Yes, a feature request implies discussion around the problem and its solution, but you can't just say "this is only a discussion don't downvote it" and expect things to go that way.

Comment: I'm curious, though, do you think *all* removal events (including post deletions) should be greyed out? After all, deleting a post also causes your reputation to simply revert back to the net-zero state it was before. Would you propose that the opposite effect also be greyed out, in which case the deletion caused the user to *re-gain* reputation, rather than lose it (and thus the event would be green).

Comment: @animuson as for your last point, yes I would say anything that is just an "undo" of previous reputation gain or loss should be grey.

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks for the UX site, that probably is a very great place to ask it! I will check it out when I get home!

Answer (score 10):

The user of coloring here has been pretty persistent with "good" and "bad" events.

A "good" event - including gaining reputation and earning badges, have always been underscored by green text or a green background.

A "bad" event - including downvotes - has always been underscored by red text.

When an account is deleted, their upvotes are removed from the system as well - so while you gained them at one point in time (positive), because their behavior caused them to be removed from the community at a specific moment in time, all of their upvotes became undone (negative).

Changing it to gray would be undesirable, since at one point, those rep gains were positive, and now they're being counted as negative instead.

Comment: For your last sentence, They aren't negative though, they were once positive, now they are neutral... you aren't loosing rep, you are just having an equilibrium bring you back to no net-gain, not net-loss, in the form of a "-5"... But who knows what's best :P

Comment: So...you'd count finding $50 on a Sunday as a gain, but then having to spend $50 on some other day (likely way in the future), you'd count it as neutral?  I'm not sure I follow/agree.

Comment: No.... I count finding $50 on the ground a gain, and someone coming up to me and saying "Sorry that fell out of my pocket" and me returning it a neutral.

Comment: If I found $50 then spent it, that would be a gain then a loss.