# Downvoting questions for vengeance

Tags: discussion, feature-request, downvotes

This is to try to improve the Stack Overflow's system of detecting fraudulent upvotes/downvotes.

In my case, everytime I have a discussion with someone, or someone gets a downvote from me, I notice in my achievements that someone downvotes my questions. This is very common, because two of my questions got downvotes with no reason, and just after having a discussion with someone.

For example, today I have two downvotes simultaneously on these questions:

- [Show only one month name in FullCalendar when WeekView wraps two different months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718332/show-only-one-month-name-in-fullcalendar-when-weekview-wraps-two-different-month)
- [jQuery Chosen: Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node':](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566288/jquery-chosen-uncaught-notfounderror-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node)

This appears since I'm discussing here:

- [Animate a display inline to block change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201312/animate-a-display-inline-to-block-change#comment63826703_38201312)

It's casual? I think no. I'm curious why Stack Overflow can't detect this kind of behaviour. There should be a form to send to moderators that we can explain that behaviour and moderators can decide if it's vengeance or it's a valid downvote.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't think 2 DVs matter too much (considering the fact that you have about 950+ answers). We do have processes in place to ensure that people don't vote "for a person" instead of a "post(s)". The DVs that you got are probably legit (atleast as of now):)

Comment: Let's start finding out whether two votes were cast out of vengeance! We could start questioning users - perhaps under threat of torture to make really sure they're not lying. We could also use a lie detector. Or a psychic. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: The question is wrong ...

Comment: By jumping for "vengeance" as an explanation, you're already loading the question. You can't tell people's reasons for downvoting if they don't make them explicit. Happens. Move on. If someone goes on a downvoting spree because you or what you write annoys them, it will be unravelled in due course. Don't complain about a couple of downvotes. It's not sufficient evidence of anything malign.

Comment: I do have the impression that the amount of "stealth serial downvoting" is increasing. Of course it's difficult to find evidence, given it's nature.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with two downvotes are not relevant, but I open this topic because it's curious that when I have a discussion or something similar appears downvotes in my questions. I am not aware of my reputation, I'm curious why this happens, and why this isn't controlled. Because batch upvotes are really fine tracked, vengeance downvotes not. Agreed also with is hard to trace vengeance downvotes, it's because I suggest a form to advice moderators, and let moderators to decide because they have more details to know if it's the same user of the discussion or not.

Comment: And it's not only me. A user here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718332/show-only-one-month-name-in-fullcalendar-when-weekview-wraps-two-different-month ask for curiosity why that question have too downvotes. It's a good asked question with all details and a clear statement, solved with an answer that have a bounty. Why sometimes this question is downvoted? Only vengeance, for sure.

Comment: @Marcos, moderators cannot see who voted for whom. They can see patterns, but they cannot *know if it's the same user of the discussion or not* (and that's a good thing IMHO).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi oh, I didn't know that, and it clears my vision. Well, sorry for the time lost. I don't know if I need to remove this question or you will close it. Thank you for your time and information.

Comment: BUT maybe it's a way to improve the system. Add a reference to who vote up or down a question or an answer.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude If we could see who voted what, we'd get even _more_ vengeance downvoting. I do believe there is a problem, but it won't be easy to solve.

Comment: Yeah, but only available to moderators, not for everyone.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Well, I still trust the moderators on SO. But I also recall that on another SE site, during their latest moderator election, there was a big controversy over one popular candidate. I'm not sure even moderators should see our votes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Ok, all is clear now. However, I insist that I grow downvotes in questions with no reason, and for sure searching vengeance against me. It's the way some people works. Always is simultaneous. I discuss with someone, suddenly appears downvotes in my questions. Thank you all for your comments. :)

Comment: In the vast majority of cases - a few downvotes here and there should just be shrugged off. If we have sufficient reason to, we can escalate concerns to the CM team to investigate and if necessary invalidate votes between individuals - however, that's not a priority for the CM team to process, and rarely necessary as people that insist on continuing with such behaviour eventually end up exposing themselves and being talked to anyway. In short - don't worry about it... there's far more important things than imaginary internet points :)

Comment: @JonClements yeah, agree, I'm not afraid of grow down reputation, but I'm disturbed by the curiosity of why some people acts as this.

Comment: @JonClements It's not just reputation (a few fake internet points), but also score. If the score of a post is low due to vengeance downvoting, then future visitors are misinformed about the value of the post.

Comment: @S.L.Barth true - but generally things work out balancing in the right direction...

Comment: I want to flag that I get occasional downvotes and guess wildly that I may just have annoyed someone but think it petty and pointless to complain. The same people's posts usually irritate me.... This post is to stand proxy for the thousands (millions???) of similar occasions on SO affecting many people. Naturally posts from people irritated mightily by downvoting can be found if you look for them just as outrages get in the news and people in happy marriages having minor arguments don't. As statistical people say, watch out for the selection problem!

Comment: @NickCox I don't understand fine... what irritates you? This post or posts of hater downvoters?

Comment: Maybe add a feature that the first downvote on a Question or Answer can not be placed unless a `comment` or a `close` are given?

Comment: @Martin only the first? And what happens with the following votes? In my case, the downvotes are produced one year after the post is published...

Comment: I am not irritated by your post. I just think you're over-reacting to small stuff. Life's too short. (Of course, life's too short for these discussions too.)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude because humans have a nature of following the leader, so as soon as a post gets `-1` (or `+1` ) then it's more likely to then get a second, third vote in the same direction. It's human nature and not worth 5 comments all saying the same thing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I get it. To me it has to do with this unpopular idea: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274319/user-was-removed-negative-reputation-color-coding . Its not the fact that you lose points, its the fact that the statistic is shown in a red color which is difficult to not interpret as "I did something bad". But you didn't so everyone expects you to not care. But then you see the red -X and then there goes your human brain again triggering an emotional response. Its how SO keeps you on your toes :)

Comment: For your information, after publish this question, appears 3 downvotes in each post I linked. So I only can think that there are so many idiots and haters and trolls in this community. I see it so many times, but this is exagerated.

Answer (score -9):

> In my case, everytime I have a discussion with someone, or someone gets a downvote for me, I notice in my notifications button that someone downvotes my questions.

*In a sense do the individual scores of the games matter to a team? Or is it the final tally of wins verses losses across a whole season?*

Focus on providing solutions which garner `the answer` marking from a poster. Whether someone is out to get you should be of little concern for they will eventually lose interest. You have enough of a buffer to weather any down voting storms; just don't take it personally.

Regardless chalk it up to the more one answers question, the more one opens themselves up criticism(s).

> or someone gets a downvote for me

Downvote sparingly and only use it as a last resort; possibly providing constructive suggestions before, *just down voting*.

Comment: @yellowantphil I suggest to leave a comment to provide guidance for the situation which in my eyes is more constructive. Allow the user to respond to the criticism instead of a *drive-by* down voting. People seem to be more apt to down vote, than to up vote.  If such consideration is given to up votes...shouldn't they be also given to down votes? IMHO

Comment: @OmegaMan you're quite wrong, there's [almost 10 times as many upvotes as there are downvotes](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508190/vote-counts)